# How to introduce a report subscription through report deployment? SSRS 2008 subscription

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportmanager

I want to be able to deploy a report and this deploy should take care of the an email subscription and set the report run schedule; I shouldn't have to manually create a subscription later on and if a new subscription is to be applied, I should be able to update the subscription with report deploy only. If somebody could provide a generic subscription element template to copy and paste in the rdl file, will be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Subscriptions are not part of the RDL file.

There is no way you can do what you want if you want it to deploy using right-click:deploy.

If you are using some automated process for deployment (rs.exe, SSRS webservice etc), you can set up subscriptions, but it would be a lot of work

Comment: Could you provide some ideas on setting up subscriptions through automated process? Could adding a post-deployment script to the report project be one of the possible solutions?
I appreciate your help.

Comment: a post deployment script wouldn't work, there are way to many dependencies in the db to make this feasible.  maybe this could point you in the right direction http://www.ericwitkowski.com/2013/05/an-introduction-to-querying-and.html

Answer (score 0):

From everything I have found, I do not see how you can create a subscription. I have found a lot on altering an existing subscription though:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn747196.aspx#bkmk_how_to

No instruction of rCREATING via PS, only mods:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156307(v=sql.130).aspx

Answer (score -1):

you may be able to create the subscription ion a STAGE environment then transfer it to Prod as part of your post deployment